# MySQL Percentage Divide count by sum

Tags: mysql

I have a table `games`, I have fields `name`, `gameStatus`, and `created_at`

This is the result I get

```
| name    | total   | percentage |   
| Caleb   | 13992   | 11.8372    |    
| Fabian  | 27570   | 23.3241    |    
| Frank   | 7181    | 6.0751     |    
| Francis | 19897   | 16.8328    |    
| Felix   | 4319    | 3.6539     |    
| Gary    | 1       | 0.0008     |    
| George  | 2405    | 2.0346     |    
| Gavin   | 16144   | 13.6577    |    
| Gab     | 22076   | 18.6762    |    
| Nigel   | 367     | 0.3105     |    
| Peter   | 2465    | 2.0854     |    
| Troy    | 1787    | 1.5118     |
```

from SQL query

```
SELECT 
  name,
  total,
  (total/total_sum * 100) AS percentage
FROM    
  (SELECT 
    name,
    COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM
    games 
  WHERE  gameStatus = 'win' 
    AND (
      created_at > '2018-03-01 12:02:26'
    ) 
  GROUP BY name) AS T  
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total_sum
  FROM
    games 
  WHERE gameStatus = 'win'
    AND (
      created_at > '2018-03-01 12:02:26'
    ) ) TS;
```

In short, I want to find out from all the games won, what percentage did each player win. I would like to do this without having to run two SQL subqueries.

SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbbaa5/3

Comment: Could you please provide an sql fiddle with data please?

Comment: Search for "conditional aggregation" - `100 * SUM(gameStatus = 'win') / COUNT(*) as win_percentage`

Comment: That is only one query. It has two subqueries, the first does not need to be a subquery though.

Comment: After reading your question again, I believe your query is the best solution performance wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was indicating in my comment, both parts do not need to be subqueries.

```
  SELECT name
     , COUNT(*) AS total
     , 100 * COUNT(*)/s.total_sum AS percentage
  FROM games 
  CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_sum 
     FROM games 
     WHERE gameStatus = 'win' 
       AND created_at > '2018-03-01 12:02:26'
  ) AS s
  WHERE gameStatus = 'win' 
    AND created_at > '2018-03-01 12:02:26'
  GROUP BY name
  ;
```

Not sure if this will actually be any faster though; I wouldn't be surprised if MySQL ends up handling them in nearly identical manners.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it profiled as being 0.00046 seconds faster than my query on a one day interval.

Comment: If you need to it across multiple days, having separate percentages for each day, this query can be tweaked slightly for that situation as well.